# Borland Decision Cube Component will not load

Tags: teechart

Iam using BDS 2006.  I have been using it for many years with Borland Decision Cube Component, and Teechart installed.  Recently, I had a problem that displayed the error message "Can't load package c:\Users\ameqamc\Documents\Borland Studio Projects\Bpl\dcldss100.bpl.  The specific module could not be found."  The module does in fact exist in this directory.  All attempts to reload it have failed.  The debug information is available at http://www.starmanpage.com/bugreport.txt.  Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to recompile the Decision Cube packages with your current TeeChart version. You could either try running DCubeRecomp.exe to do so or, if it fails, do it manually following the instructions at the text file in *C:\Program Files\Steema Software\TeeChart 2012 for Delphi 2006\Delphi10\Decision Cube*. You can find DCubeRecomp.exe at the same location as the manual compilation instructions..